# Moving a large Joomla site over SSH

Tags: joomla, ssh

I'm moving a large Joomla site on version 2.5 with over 20,000 articles, images, etc into a new account I created in WHM because the current install has alot of bugs and  'work-a-arounds' to keep it going whenever there's an issue. I'm installing Joomla 3 in the new account, but with the large number of articles and images that are linked into it, I was going to use the [J2XML Plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15807) to export the articles and import them, but not sure that's the best route to go with this.

I considered using terminal to SSH into the old account and copy that over into the new one and just do an upgrade of Joomla from there. Once again, I don't know if that's the wisest choice to go with this doing that there may still be underlying issues with the install itself even if it's upgraded.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

J2XML will not handle this number of articles, it also misses a lot of articles and doesn't maintain IDs (if I'm not mistaken). The only reason you might want to use SSH is to copy over the images.

You will need to re-create the website from scratch, or at least do many things manually, such as content migration, re-installation of extensions and re-creation of modules, etc...

Comment: So copying over the site via SSH from one account to another and then upgrading the new account won't help?